Why a custom QWidget doesn't show in a QGridLayout?
I'm trying to build a custom toolbar for my application.
But the toolbar doesn't show when I put it in the QGridLayout of the application.
This is a test code that regenerates the issue.
from sys import argv
from sys import exit as ex
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGridLayout, QTextEdit, QWidget, QSizePolicy


class Toolbar(QWidget):
    def __init__(
        self,
        parent: QWidget | None = None,
        flags: Qt.WindowType = Qt.WindowType.Widget,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent, flags)
        self.setMinimumHeight(50)


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(
        self, parent: QWidget | None = None, flags: Qt.WindowType = Qt.WindowType.Window
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent, flags)
        self.__setup_ui()

    def __setup_ui(self) -> None:
        self.grid_layout = QGridLayout()
        toolbar = Toolbar()
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(toolbar, 0, 0, 1, 4)
        text_edit = QTextEdit()
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(text_edit, 1, 0, 2, 1)
        text_edit = QTextEdit()
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(text_edit, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        text_edit = QTextEdit()
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(text_edit, 1, 2, 2, 1)
        text_edit = QTextEdit()
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(text_edit, 1, 3, 2, 1)
        text_edit = QTextEdit()
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(text_edit, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.setLayout(self.grid_layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QApplication(argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    ex(application.exec())

This is what it looks like when we run it.

When I put a QTextEdit instead the toolbar.
toolbar = QTextEdit()

I get this.

I saw this.
https://forum.qt.io/topic/97929/custom-qwidget-doesn-t-show-up-in-qgridlayout-only-in-a-new-window/7
So I tried this.
self.grid_layout.addWidget(toolbar.setVisible(True), 0, 0, 1, 4)

I found this.
https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/overviews/layout.html
That says:

Custom Widgets in Layouts
When you make your own widget class, you should also communicate its layout properties.
If the widget uses one of Qt’s layouts, this is already taken care of.
If the widget does not have any child widgets, or uses a manual layout,
you can change the behavior of the widget using any or all of the following mechanisms:

Reimplement sizeHint() to return the preferred size of the widget.
Reimplement minimumSizeHint() to return the smallest size the widget can have.
Call setSizePolicy() to specify the space requirements of the widget.


So I tried this.
class Toolbar(QWidget):
    def __init__(
        self,
        parent: QWidget | None = None,
        flags: Qt.WindowType = Qt.WindowType.Widget,
    ) -> None:
        ...
        self.setSizePolicy(
            QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Minimum)
        )

But I got same result.
Could you help me figure out why this custom QWidget does not show, please.

I cannot reproduce this with Qt 6.6, and it should also not happen as soon as the widget has a minimum height set, which is what you're doing. Note that your attempt with setVisible(True) is wrong, other than pointless: 1. setVisible() returns None, so using addWidget() is no-op; 2. by default, child widgets added to a parent are automatically shown as soon as the parent is. Setting the size policy is also not intended for your purpose, and should be left as the default (Preferred). Please add relevant debugging details: PyQt, Qt and OS versions.

This is the output of pip freeze command
PyQt6==6.7.0
PyQt6-Qt6==6.7.1
PyQt6-sip==13.6.0
six==1.16.0
I'm also on Python 3.12.2 and Windows 10

Try to downgrade to Qt 6.7.0 (note that PyQt and Qt version are rarely the same: the PyQt version refers to the binding, while the Qt one refers to the actual Qt library). Eventually try downgrading to 6.6.

Thank you for the help. I updated Python to 3.12.4 and downgraded PyQt6 and PyQt6-Qt6 to version 6.6.0, and the problem seems to not exist with these versions. Please write an answer that I can take as a correct answer to the question for others. It seems that the issue lies with the new version of PyQt6, specifically version 6.7.1. Should I report this issue, and if so, where should I do that?

Qt 6.7.1 seems to be suffering a few relatively important problems (even though it was intended as a "simple" bug fix release). It seems strange, though, that such an important and quite elementary issue wasn't discovered so far. I did a basic research on codereview.qt-project.org changes about QLayout and related classes within the last few months, and I only found results about QML layouts, which, in theory, should have no relation with QLayouts (except for this, so I'd assume that nothing should have been changed for 6.7.1.

I also doubt that a different python version should have any effect, but I cannot completely exclude that. I'd suggest you to do further testing with more minimal examples: 1. with QGridLayout, just add one or two (possibly, expanding, like QTextEdit or QScrollArea) widgets in the second row and eventually playing around with column and row spans; 2. do the same with a basic QVBoxLayout with the custom widget on top and a vertical expanding one after that. If the issue still persists, consider filing a bug on https://bugreports.qt.io with a proper MRE and detailed environment info.

I cannot reproduce this at all on Linux using Qt-6.7.1 with PyQt-6.7.0 (and Python-3.12.3, FWIW). I also tried setting up a venv so I could try the pip-specific builds, but that also works exactly as expected.

@musicamante What platform did you test on? I don't have access to a Windows machine, so I can't confirm this is a platform-specific issue. This is the second problem with Qt-6.7.1 I've seen recently that seems only reproducible by the OP on Windows.

@ekhumoro I also tested it with Python 3.12.3 and PyQt6-Qt6 6.7.1 PyQt6-sip 13.6.0 PyQt6 6.7.0 on WSL2 and ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS the problem wasn't there. maybe the problem is only happening on Windows.

@kamrannasirizad Well there's no "maybe", since it is only happening on Windows with Qt-6.7.1, as you've now confirmed ;-)

@ekhumoro I cannot test on Windows too, but it seems clear it's a Windows only bug. What's strange is that I wasn't able to find any relevant changes in QLayout related sources in the last months, and I only found a couple of slightly related reports: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-124151 and https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-2711 (but that should not be relevant); still, the changes shouldn't affect a different behavior depending on the OS.

@musicamante Yeah - if it was affecting me, I would want to experiment quite a bit to see exactly what triggers the issue and maybe find a work-around (e.g. perhaps by reimplementing sizeHint). I have no idea what the underlying cause might be though - something compiler-related maybe? If the OP is using pip, it might also be worth testing with PySide6, just in case there's some PyQt6-specific build issues (unlikely, but you never know).

@kamrannasirizad are you able to install PySide (ensuring that it has the same Qt version, 6.7.1) and repeat the test with it? Also, does it change anything if you make a persistent reference to the widget (self.toolbar = Toolbar())?

@musicamante I am really confused about this now. I tested the same code with the same environment (PyQt6==6.7.0 PyQt6-Qt6==6.7.1 PyQt6-sip==13.6.0 and Python 3.12.2) on the same machine a few seconds ago, the problem is gone. If I hadn't saved those images from it, I'd say that I was high.

@kamrannasirizad Then the only possible explanations I could think of is that you were running another file, or inadvertently using another class that didn't have the minimum height set. Considering the research ekhumoro and I did, there seem to be no evidence of code changes relating layout geometries in QLayout or QWidget between 6.7.0 and 6.7.1 (the only slightly related result I found was with QML layouts, which don't have common code with the QtWidgets counterparts), and unless you're able to recreate the issue again, this seems to be a non reproducible problem.
